# Why does a trait type `Box<dyn Error>` error with "Sized is not implemented" but `async fn() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>` works?

Tags: rust

I’ve the following simplified code.

```
use async_trait::async_trait; // 0.1.36
use std::error::Error;

#[async_trait]
trait Metric: Send {
    type Output;
    type Error: Error;

    async fn refresh_metric(&mut self) -> Result<Self::Output, Self::Error>;
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct StaticMetric;

#[async_trait]
impl Metric for StaticMetric {
    type Output = ();
    type Error = Box<dyn Error>;

    async fn refresh_metric(&mut self) -> Result<Self::Output, Self::Error> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

struct LocalSystemData<T> {
    inner: T,
}

impl<T> LocalSystemData<T>
where
    T: Metric,
    <T as Metric>::Error: 'static,
{
    fn new(inner: T) -> LocalSystemData<T> {
        LocalSystemData { inner }
    }

    async fn refresh_all(&mut self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
        self.inner.refresh_metric().await?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut sys_data = LocalSystemData::new(StaticMetric::default());
    sys_data.refresh_all().await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e84c1659325a225e6437120c5f7263f0)

The compiler throws the following error

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:18:18
   |
5  | trait Metric: Send {
   |       ------ required by a bound in this
6  |     type Output;
7  |     type Error: Error;
   |                 ----- required by this bound in `Metric`
...
18 |     type Error = Box<dyn Error>;
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)`
   = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::error::Error` for `std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>`
```

I'm not really sure if I understand the problem correct.

I’m using `Box<dyn Error>` because I don’t have a concrete type and boxing an error can handle all errors. In my implementation of `LocaSystemData`, I added `<T as Metric>::Error: 'static` (the compiler gave me that hint, not my idea). After I added the `'static` requirement the compiler complains about that the size is unknown. This happens because the size of a `'static` type should always known at compile time because the implication of static.

I changed the `Metric` trait so that I get rid of the `type Error;` Now I've the following async trait function and my code compiles

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6255c6d754678e7422c5b1ea794391df)

```
async fn refresh_metric(&mut self) -> Result<Self::Output, Box<dyn Error>>;
```

Why does my second version compile and the first one does not? For me as a human the code does exactly the same. I feel I tricked the compiler :-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is a bit misleading, as it represents an intermediate issue that emerged during type constraint resolution. The same problem can be reproduced without async.

```
use std::error::Error;

trait Metric {
    type Error: Error;
}

struct StaticMetric;

impl Metric for StaticMetric {
    type Error = Box<dyn Error>;
}
```

The root of the problem is that **`Box<dyn Error>` does not implement `std::error::Error`**. And as specified by the implementation of [`From<Box<E>>` for `Box<dyn Error>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-From%3CE%3E), the inner type `E` must also be `Sized`.

```
impl<'a, E: Error + 'a> From<E> for Box<dyn Error + 'a>
```

Therefore, `Box<dyn Error>` should not be assigned to the associated type `Metric::Error`.

Other than getting rid of the associated type altogether, this can be fixed by introducing your own new error type which can flow into the main function.

```
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct MyErr;

impl std::fmt::Display for MyErr {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        f.write_str("I AM ERROR")
    }
}
impl Error for MyErr {}

#[async_trait]
impl Metric for StaticMetric {
    type Output = ();
    type Error = MyErr;

    async fn refresh_metric(&mut self) -> Result<Self::Output, Self::Error> {
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=327d46749f59806a5e03b6f6be73fd25)

See also:

- [How do you define custom `Error` types in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42584368/how-do-you-define-custom-error-types-in-rust)
- [How can I implement From for both concrete Error types and Box<Error> in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55122541)
- [Consider relaxing the `Sized` requirement in `impl Error for Box<T>`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/104485)

Comment: That is crystal clear. But why will this work? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2c951bb5050424cbd3df907dce3d7c0f

Rust requires `impl Error` in the error type if you want to use the `?` syntax. So if the trait is not implemented for `Box<dyn Error>` (which is definitely not). Why does the error propagation work in my example and not in my question code.

Comment: @createproblem The `?` syntax actually does not require the type to implement `Error`. It requires a conversion from the given error variant type to the error defined by the function signature via `From`. Here's [another example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c7817553611fe958a28464c83036fd45) which doesn't use any error types.

Comment: I'm totally agree with you, look at this https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c6b7a7bb16ac363681711fafc9b13308 the compiler tells me, that the `Error` trait is not implemented which is correct, but why should it be? As you can see the `?` works in `main` function but not in the `struct`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have updated the question with a few more details. In that other case, it's because of a quirk in the implementations of `From`, which does not let you convert a `Box<dyn Error>` to another `Box<dyn Error>`. There is one attempt to resolve this [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/58974), but it would have had severe implications to the language.