# How do I work around the "upstream crates may add a new impl of trait" error when I also control the upstream crate?

Tags: rust, types, compiler-errors, traits

Suppose I have 2 library crates in a workspace: A and B. In crate A, I create a public struct `StructA`. Crate B depends on crate A and has the following code in `src/lib.rs`:

```rust
use A::StructA;

struct StructB;

impl<T: Into<StructA>, E> From<Result<T, E>> for StructB {
    fn from(value: Result<T, E>) -> Self {
        Self
    }
}

impl<T: Into<StructA>> From<T> for StructB {
    fn from(value: T) -> Self {
        println!("Into StructB!"); // included so the implementations are different
        Self
    }
}
```

The code above will not compile and gives the warning: `` note: upstream crates may add a new impl of trait `std::convert::From<std::result::Result<_, _>>` for type `A::StructA` in future versions ``

The problem I face is similar to the one posed in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63136970/how-do-i-work-around-the-upstream-crates-may-add-a-new-impl-of-trait-error). Unlike the person asking that question though, I can actually control whether the upstream crate implements `From<Result<_, _>>` for `StructA`. Is there a way to make it clear to dependents of crate A that it will never add a specific impl in a later version?

Comment: You don't fully control the upstream crate. Users of your crates can add [overrides](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html) and do whatever they like. So the fact that both crates are by the same author (or whatever criterion you propose) does not matter to the Rust compiler. The answers to the question you linked to are valid answers to this one – unsatisfying though that may be :(

Comment: `Is there a way to make it clear to dependents of crate A that it will never add a specific impl in a later version?` answer is, no.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is such way!

But it won't satisfy you, because it is nightly-only and internal for std. The lang team may decide to expose it in the future, though. See https://github.com/rust-lang/negative-impls-initiative/issues/1.

This is done with negative impls.

In crate `A`:

```rust
#![feature(negative_impls)]

impl<T: Into<StructA>, E> !Into<StructA> for Result<T, E> {}
```

In crate `B`:

```rust
#![feature(with_negative_coherence)]

use A::StructA;

struct StructB;

impl<T: Into<StructA>, E> From<Result<T, E>> for StructB {
    fn from(value: Result<T, E>) -> Self {
        Self
    }
}

impl<T: Into<StructA>> From<T> for StructB {
    fn from(value: T) -> Self {
        println!("Into StructB!"); // included so the implementations are different
        Self
    }
}
```