Getting default value based on type parameter
I have the following generic function which deserializes a value and returns a tuple of std::ops::Bounds based. In case the value indicates an empty range I want to return an open interval containing twice the same value to represent the empty interval.
I thought the easiest would be to rely on the std::default::Default trait for this:
impl<T, ST> FromSql<Range<ST>, Pg> for (Bound<T>, Bound<T>)
where
    T: FromSql<ST, Pg> + std::default::Default,
{
    fn from_sql(value: PgValue<'_>) -> deserialize::Result<Self> {
        let mut bytes = value.as_bytes();
        let flags: RangeFlags = RangeFlags::from_bits_truncate(bytes.read_u8()?);


        if flags.contains(RangeFlags::EMPTY) {
            return (Bound::Excluded(T::default()), Bound::Excluded(T::default());
        }

The problem I'm facing is that not all input types implement the Default trait. Since the types are from external libraries I cannot implement Default for them and I can't figure out a way to write a wrapper which re-uses Default::default() for the types which implement it so that I just need to handle the cases which don't have default values.
Is that possible in Rust or do I need to explicitly implement the default values for all types I expect?
The C++ equivalent for what I'm looking for would be along these lines:
template <typename T>
struct MyDefault {
  static T default_()  { return T(); };
};

struct NoDefault {
  NoDefault(int magic);
};

template <>
struct MyDefault<NoDefault> {
  static NoDefault default_() {
    return NoDefault(42);
  }
};

int main() {
    int a = MyDefault<int>::default_();
    NoDefault b = MyDefault<NoDefault>::default_();
}

The question is based on my MR here: https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/pull/4295

You can not implement Default for a type of an extern library, but you can make your own trait and delegate to Default in case of a type that implements it:
trait MyDefault {
    fn my_default() -> Self;
}

impl<T:Default> MyDefault for T  {
    fn my_default() -> Self {
        Self::default()
    }
}

For all types that doesn't implement Default, you can implement MyDefault since MyDefault comes from your crate.

That what I tried but then I end up with "conflicting implementations of trait MyDefault for type OffsetDateTime ... upstream crates may add a new impl of trait std::default::Default for type OffsetDateTime in future versions" (OffsetDateTime being the external type that doesn't implement std::default::Default). Am I overlooking something?

@Moritz:  IMHO you have two choices: 1.) Implement your trait for each type separately. A macro could help, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63136970.
2.) Use unstable rust, make a marker trait to mark the no-default types, and use for the generic implementation a negative implementation bound, see: https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/negative-impls.html. What way ist better depends on your default/non-default ratio and whether you can afford unstable rust.

It is correct that

Since the types are from external libraries I cannot implement Default for them

For this:

I can't figure out a way to write a wrapper which re-uses Default::default() for the types which implement it

How about define a custom trait Defaultable that can provide a default value for types that implement Default.
For types that don't implement Default, you can provide a fallback implementation.
use std::ops::Bound;
use std::default::Default;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

// a custom define of Defaultable
trait Defaultable {
    fn default_value() -> Self;
}

// Defaultable for types that has Default
impl<T: Default> Defaultable for T {
    fn default_value() -> T {
        T::default()
    }
}

// a fallback implementation for non-Default types
struct NoDefault;

// Defaultable for types that don't have Default
impl Defaultable for NoDefault {
    fn default_value() -> NoDefault {
        NoDefault
    }
}

Anyway, your question is not a C++, but rust. So, it may not be tagged as C++.

That works as long as the "NoDefault" type is part of my crate. But as soon as I implement "Defaultable" for some external type which doesn't implement "std::default::Default" I get "conflicting implementations of trait MyDefault for type OffsetDateTime ... upstream crates may add a new impl of trait std::default::Default for type OffsetDateTime in future versions" (OffsetDateTime being the external type that doesn't implement std::default::Default).

If this helps as you state That works as long as the "NoDefault" type is part of my crate.. please upvote. I'll check your other issues later.

This is commonly known in Rust as the "orphan rule" where trait implementations cannot be made on types existing in external cargo workspaces, i.e. std::collections::Vec.
Creating a custom Default-like trait and implementing it is generally an anti-pattern. Instead of doing this try leveraging the newtype pattern and implementing Default directly.
struct Bounds<A, B, T: FromSql<A, B> + Sized>(T)

impl<A, B, T: FromSql<A, B> + Sized> Default for Bounds<A, B, T> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        todo!()
    }
}

If Bounds is too unconstrained for you to work with in a practical way, you might simply use an enum to capture your states.
enum Bounds<A, B, T: FromSql<A, B> + Sized> {
    Nil,
    Lo(T),
    Hi(T),
    All(T)
}

impl<A, B, T: FromSql<A, B> + Sized> Default for Bounds<A, B, T> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::Nil
    }
}


The New Type Idiom would mean to use the custom Bounds type instead of the std::ops::Bound everywhere in the code base, right? So if a lot of the code base uses std::ops::Bound that would mean a lot of changes.

You're right, @Moritz, I did not consider that. Perhaps implementations on From<std::ops::Bound> (and implicitly Into<Bounds> from implementing From) would make it feasible to continue using existing code mostly as it is. Otherwise, the tweaks could be as simple as systematically targeting where .into() calls need to be placed so that std::ops::Bound values are given where they might be needed.
